# PHP & @: Is this valid?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Code below works, but I'm not sure it is valid:

```
// It should print $param or $_GET['uuu'] if isset:

function test($param) {
    echo @$_GET['uuu'] ? $_GET['uuu'] : $param;

}

test('param');
```

Thanx for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

If it wasn't *valid*, it wouldn't *work*.

It is just really terrible practice to use `@` in place of `isset()` to merely save keystrokes or make your code look cleaner, because that's not what it does. What it does is attempt to access your variable *regardless of whether it is set*, and suppress the `E_NOTICE` that inevitably comes up if the variable doesn't exist.

So don't use `@` for checking variables as it's not designed for that purpose. Use `isset()` which does serve that purpose:

```
echo isset($_GET['uuu']) ? $_GET['uuu'] : $param;
```

Comment: OK, I konw, but what is the difference?

Comment: @lisek @ simply tells PHP, "don't tell me about this mistake". isset() is actually the way of _resolving_ this mistake.

Comment: @Jimmie Lin: Great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`@` suppresses warning message if `$_GET['uuu']` doesn't exist. This is not usually a recommended practice, as it shies away error messages that could be useful to you. For instance, in this example, I wouldn't know whether `$_GET['uuu']` is really not set, or there's `form` error in my html that doesn't send `uuu` to the server.

Answer (score 2):

The @ symbol is used just to ignore errors and warnings. It is not good practice to use it. I'd suggest you try **NOT** to use it.

As for the function, it is valid.